# How to migrate test cases from ALM to MTM 2017 using any automated API

Tags: alm, microsoft-test-manager

We have test cases already present in ALM and now we want to migrate to MTM(Microsoft Test Manager 2017).

Already viewed some tool which are not supported by TFS and there are some 3rd party tools which are paid. We are looking for some exposed API's which can be automated and support migration of test cases from ALM to TFS.

Also free source tool would help but didn't found any tool yet.

Can someone please help to know how to migrate all the test cases from ALM to TFS?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is export your tests to xls and create a migration application that will use TFS API and import those tests.
For export check this [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2721/how-to-export-test-cases-from-test-plan-in-qc)
For TFS API check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) (check test and test plan section)